# update llama index default model for text-davinci-004 deprecation

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I have the python 3 code below.  I'm using llama_index along with openai to create an index object, save it locally, then load it and query it.  This code used to work fine but recently I tried running it and got the error message below.  It looks like openai deprecated the text-davinci-003 model and possibly llama_index uses it by default somewhere under the hood.  I've tried updating the code in several places to use the gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct model, but I'm still getting the same error.  Can anyone see what the issue might be and suggest how to update the code to resolve it?

code:

```
from config import api_key

apikey=api_key

import os

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = apikey


# creating index from corpus


# Load data into 'Documents' a custom type by LlamaIndex
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader('./data').load_data()


# create vector store
from llama_index import GPTVectorStoreIndex
# index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents,
                                          embed_model='gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct')


saved_context_dict=index.storage_context.to_dict()


# saving index object to reduce cost when querying
import json

# Serialize data into file:
json.dump( saved_context_dict, open( "recruiter_storage_context_dict.json", 'w' ) )



prompt_submit1="""Please return the email title of all emails with positions containing the term data scientist, that have been sent to job seeker. Please return them as a quoted comma separated list."""


def query_index(api_key,context_dict,prompt_submit):
    
    # load saved context

    import os


    os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = api_key


    # using previously saved index
    import json

    saved_context=json.load( open(context_dict) )

    from llama_index import StorageContext, load_index_from_storage

    # rebuild storage context

#     storage_context=StorageContext.from_dict(saved_context) 
    storage_context=StorageContext.from_dict(saved_context)

    stored_index=load_index_from_storage(storage_context,
                                            embed_model='gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct')


#     query_engine = stored_index.as_query_engine()
    query_engine = stored_index.as_query_engine(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct')
    response = query_engine.query(prompt_submit)
    
    return response
    
    
index_response=query_index(api_key= apikey,
                          context_dict="recruiter_storage_context_dict.json",
                          prompt_submit=prompt_submit1)

print(index_response)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 3
      1 # getting most relevant text chunks from index
----> 3 index_response=query_index(api_key= apikey,
      4                           context_dict="recruiter_storage_context_dict.json",
      5                           prompt_submit=prompt_submit1)
      7 print(index_response)

Cell In[31], line 29, in query_index(api_key, context_dict, prompt_submit)
     27 #     query_engine = stored_index.as_query_engine()
     28     query_engine = stored_index.as_query_engine(model='gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct')
---> 29     response = query_engine.query(prompt_submit)
     31     return response

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/indices/query/base.py:23, in BaseQueryEngine.query(self, str_or_query_bundle)
     21 if isinstance(str_or_query_bundle, str):
     22     str_or_query_bundle = QueryBundle(str_or_query_bundle)
---> 23 response = self._query(str_or_query_bundle)
     24 return response

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/query_engine/retriever_query_engine.py:152, in RetrieverQueryEngine._query(self, query_bundle)
    145 nodes = self.retrieve(query_bundle)
    146 self.callback_manager.on_event_end(
    147     CBEventType.RETRIEVE,
    148     payload={EventPayload.NODES: nodes},
    149     event_id=retrieve_id,
    150 )
--> 152 response = self._response_synthesizer.synthesize(
    153     query=query_bundle,
    154     nodes=nodes,
    155 )
    157 self.callback_manager.on_event_end(
    158     CBEventType.QUERY,
    159     payload={EventPayload.RESPONSE: response},
    160     event_id=query_id,
    161 )
    162 return response

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/response_synthesizers/base.py:124, in BaseSynthesizer.synthesize(self, query, nodes, additional_source_nodes)
    121 if isinstance(query, str):
    122     query = QueryBundle(query_str=query)
--> 124 response_str = self.get_response(
    125     query_str=query.query_str,
    126     text_chunks=[
    127         n.node.get_content(metadata_mode=MetadataMode.LLM) for n in nodes
    128     ],
    129 )
    131 additional_source_nodes = additional_source_nodes or []
    132 source_nodes = list(nodes) + list(additional_source_nodes)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/response_synthesizers/compact_and_refine.py:34, in CompactAndRefine.get_response(self, query_str, text_chunks, **response_kwargs)
     30 # use prompt helper to fix compact text_chunks under the prompt limitation
     31 # TODO: This is a temporary fix - reason it's temporary is that
     32 # the refine template does not account for size of previous answer.
     33 new_texts = self._make_compact_text_chunks(query_str, text_chunks)
---> 34 response = super().get_response(
     35     query_str=query_str, text_chunks=new_texts, **response_kwargs
     36 )
     37 return response

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/response_synthesizers/refine.py:49, in Refine.get_response(self, query_str, text_chunks, **response_kwargs)
     45 for text_chunk in text_chunks:
     46     if prev_response_obj is None:
     47         # if this is the first chunk, and text chunk already
     48         # is an answer, then return it
---> 49         response = self._give_response_single(
     50             query_str,
     51             text_chunk,
     52         )
     53     else:
     54         response = self._refine_response_single(
     55             prev_response_obj, query_str, text_chunk
     56         )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/response_synthesizers/refine.py:80, in Refine._give_response_single(self, query_str, text_chunk, **response_kwargs)
     78 for cur_text_chunk in text_chunks:
     79     if response is None and not self._streaming:
---> 80         response = self._service_context.llm_predictor.predict(
     81             text_qa_template,
     82             context_str=cur_text_chunk,
     83         )
     84     elif response is None and self._streaming:
     85         response = self._service_context.llm_predictor.stream(
     86             text_qa_template,
     87             context_str=cur_text_chunk,
     88         )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/llm_predictor/base.py:123, in LLMPredictor.predict(self, prompt, **prompt_args)
    121 else:
    122     formatted_prompt = prompt.format(llm=self._llm, **prompt_args)
--> 123     response = self._llm.complete(formatted_prompt)
    124     output = response.text
    126 logger.debug(output)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/llms/openai.py:72, in OpenAI.complete(self, prompt, **kwargs)
     70 else:
     71     complete_fn = self._complete
---> 72 return complete_fn(prompt, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/llms/openai.py:183, in OpenAI._complete(self, prompt, **kwargs)
    180     max_tokens = self._get_max_token_for_prompt(prompt)
    181     all_kwargs["max_tokens"] = max_tokens
--> 183 response = completion_with_retry(
    184     is_chat_model=self._is_chat_model,
    185     max_retries=self.max_retries,
    186     prompt=prompt,
    187     stream=False,
    188     **all_kwargs,
    189 )
    190 text = response["choices"][0]["text"]
    191 return CompletionResponse(
    192     text=text,
    193     raw=response,
    194 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/llms/openai_utils.py:123, in completion_with_retry(is_chat_model, max_retries, **kwargs)
    120     client = get_completion_endpoint(is_chat_model)
    121     return client.create(**kwargs)
--> 123 return _completion_with_retry(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py:289, in BaseRetrying.wraps.<locals>.wrapped_f(*args, **kw)
    287 @functools.wraps(f)
    288 def wrapped_f(*args: t.Any, **kw: t.Any) -> t.Any:
--> 289     return self(f, *args, **kw)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py:379, in Retrying.__call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    377 retry_state = RetryCallState(retry_object=self, fn=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    378 while True:
--> 379     do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
    380     if isinstance(do, DoAttempt):
    381         try:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py:314, in BaseRetrying.iter(self, retry_state)
    312 is_explicit_retry = fut.failed and isinstance(fut.exception(), TryAgain)
    313 if not (is_explicit_retry or self.retry(retry_state)):
--> 314     return fut.result()
    316 if self.after is not None:
    317     self.after(retry_state)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:451, in Future.result(self, timeout)
    449     raise CancelledError()
    450 elif self._state == FINISHED:
--> 451     return self.__get_result()
    453 self._condition.wait(timeout)
    455 if self._state in [CANCELLED, CANCELLED_AND_NOTIFIED]:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py:403, in Future.__get_result(self)
    401 if self._exception:
    402     try:
--> 403         raise self._exception
    404     finally:
    405         # Break a reference cycle with the exception in self._exception
    406         self = None

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tenacity/__init__.py:382, in Retrying.__call__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    380 if isinstance(do, DoAttempt):
    381     try:
--> 382         result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
    383     except BaseException:  # noqa: B902
    384         retry_state.set_exception(sys.exc_info())  # type: ignore[arg-type]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/llms/openai_utils.py:121, in completion_with_retry.<locals>._completion_with_retry(**kwargs)
    118 @retry_decorator
    119 def _completion_with_retry(**kwargs: Any) -> Any:
    120     client = get_completion_endpoint(is_chat_model)
--> 121     return client.create(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/completion.py:25, in Completion.create(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     23 while True:
     24     try:
---> 25         return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
     26     except TryAgain as e:
     27         if timeout is not None and time.time() > start + timeout:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py:153, in EngineAPIResource.create(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, request_id, api_version, organization, **params)
    127 @classmethod
    128 def create(
    129     cls,
   (...)
    136     **params,
    137 ):
    138     (
    139         deployment_id,
    140         engine,
   (...)
    150         api_key, api_base, api_type, api_version, organization, **params
    151     )
--> 153     response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
    154         "post",
    155         url,
    156         params=params,
    157         headers=headers,
    158         stream=stream,
    159         request_id=request_id,
    160         request_timeout=request_timeout,
    161     )
    163     if stream:
    164         # must be an iterator
    165         assert not isinstance(response, OpenAIResponse)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py:298, in APIRequestor.request(self, method, url, params, headers, files, stream, request_id, request_timeout)
    277 def request(
    278     self,
    279     method,
   (...)
    286     request_timeout: Optional[Union[float, Tuple[float, float]]] = None,
    287 ) -> Tuple[Union[OpenAIResponse, Iterator[OpenAIResponse]], bool, str]:
    288     result = self.request_raw(
    289         method.lower(),
    290         url,
   (...)
    296         request_timeout=request_timeout,
    297     )
--> 298     resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
    299     return resp, got_stream, self.api_key

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py:700, in APIRequestor._interpret_response(self, result, stream)
    692     return (
    693         self._interpret_response_line(
    694             line, result.status_code, result.headers, stream=True
    695         )
    696         for line in parse_stream(result.iter_lines())
    697     ), True
    698 else:
    699     return (
--> 700         self._interpret_response_line(
    701             result.content.decode("utf-8"),
    702             result.status_code,
    703             result.headers,
    704             stream=False,
    705         ),
    706         False,
    707     )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/LLMenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py:763, in APIRequestor._interpret_response_line(self, rbody, rcode, rheaders, stream)
    761 stream_error = stream and "error" in resp.data
    762 if stream_error or not 200 <= rcode < 300:
--> 763     raise self.handle_error_response(
    764         rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders, stream_error=stream_error
    765     )
    766 return resp

InvalidRequestError: The model `text-davinci-003` has been deprecated, learn more here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to import `ServiceContext` from the `llama_index` module. It's this that will accept your `LLMPredictor` as an argument. You then pass the service context to the `load_index_from_storage` function.

Example:

```py
llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(
    temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=512))

storage_context = StorageContext.from_dict(saved_context)
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor)

load_index_from_storage(storage_context, service_context=service_context)
```

Comment: @user3623033 thanks for getting back to me with this.  I tried your suggestion and I'm getting an error that "ChatOpenAI" is not defined.  I've got langchain 0.0.247,llama-index 0.7.2,openai 0.27.8 installed in my env.  I've tried importing ChatOpenAI from each with no luck.  Is there versions of each I need installed?  On a deeper level I'm trying to understand what llama_index is doing under the hood, do you know is this an example of semantic search or RAG?

Comment: @user3476463 `ChatOpenAI` is new in the latest version of llama-index. In your version I believe you can use `OpenAI` which has since been deprecated.